# An autohomeomorphism on a normed linear space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. Let $x_{0}\in B_{1}^{(0)}=\{x\in X : \|x\|<1\}$ and define

$$
\begin{array}{lcccl}
h & : & X & \longrightarrow & X\\
 & & x & \longrightarrow &  h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
x+(1-\|x\|)x_{0} & if & \|x\|<1 \\\\
x & if & \|x\|\geq 1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
$$
I have managed to show that for all $x,y\in X$, we have that $(1-\|x_{0}\|)\|x-y\|\leq \|h(x)-h(y)\|\leq   (1+\|x_{0}\|)\|x-y\|$. Then $h$ is injective, my question is how can I show that $h$ is surjective? In this case, by the inequalities above, $h$ is an autohomeomorphism on $X$.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $h$ is surjective on $X \setminus B_1^{(0)}$ so let $y \in B_1^{(0)}$ be fixed. We wish to find $x \in B_1^{(0)}$ such that $h(x) = y$.

Consider the continuous function $f : [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ given by
$$f(t) = \|y-tx_0\|+t-1.$$
We have
$$f(0) = \|y\|-1 < 0, \quad f(1) = \|y-x_0\| \ge 0$$
so by the intermediate value theorem there is some $t \in (0,1]$ such that $f(t) = 0$.

Define $$x := y-tx_0.$$
Then $$0 = f(t) = \|x\|+t-1$$ so $t = 1-\|x\|$ and hence
$$x = y - (1-\|x\|)x_0.$$
Also $\|x\| = 1-t \in [0,1)$ so $x \in B_1^{(0)}$. Furthermore
$$h(x) = x+(1-\|x\|)x_0 = y - (1-\|x\|)x_0 + (1-\|x\|)x_0 = y.$$

Comment: Great, I was actually trying to calculate the inverse of $h$ explicitly. Excuse me, how did you come up with defining f?

Comment: @gaam2296 From $y = x+(1-\|x\|)x_0$ we try to solve for $x$. We get $x = y-(1-\|x\|)x_0$ so it must be of the form $x = y-tx_0$ where $t$ satisfies the equation $$t = 1-\|y-tx_0\|.$$ Moving everything to one side, we need to prove that $f(t) = \|y-tx_0\|+t-1$ has a zero.

Comment: Great, very good idea. Thanks